# Multiple sortable lists with jquery sortable and Meteor Blaze

Tags: meteor, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists that I want to make sortable with jQuery UI. Problem is only one list turns sortable/draggable.

jqtest.html:

```
<body>
 <div id="list1">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
 </div>

 <div id="list2">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
 </div>
</body>
```

jqtest.js

Not working:

```
UI.body.rendered = function(){
this.$("#list1", "#list2").sortable();
}
```

This works:

```
UI.body.rendered = function(){
 this.$("#list1").sortable();
 this.$("#list2").sortable();
}
```

By looking in the console I can see that the ui-sortable class is only added to list1 so that is probably why it's not working. I tried adding the class manually to list2 but that did not work either(the class is added but no dragging possible).

I got it to work by duplicating the sortable call for each list but that does not seem very dry to me and probably has performance impact.

Comment: As a side note the html you have is invalid… `<li>` should be direct child of `<ul>`

Comment: Instead of jQuery, you may want to use the native HTML5 drag'n'drop API, with [this Meteor wrapper](https://github.com/themeteorchef/html5-sortable/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by combining the ids into a single comma-separated string:

```js
this.$('#list1, #list2').sortable();
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Where did I get that syntax from? Thank you!

Comment: jquery just uses the normal [css selector syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). So `X, Y` means all the Xs on the page and all of the Ys.